# Calculate values from consecutive rows (two different tables)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am working with two tables, table1 and table2. The first table (table1) contains a column called "codes" which contains unique identifiers (codes)  corresponding to a set of points which are placed on a path. The second table (table2) contains the distances between those points as follows:

```
code1| code2| distance

252| 252| 1000|
```

I would like to add the distances between consecutive points (point in row 2 against point row 1, point in row 3 against point in row 2 etc) to table1 as follows (distances are made up):

```
codes distance

    251 0
    252 1000
    253 20000
```

Sample data:

```
table1<-structure(list(codes = c("251", "253", "259", "261")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                         -4L), class = "data.frame")



table2<-structure(list(dist = c(43733.8720639044, 50226.4427668293, 13373.4575031321, 
                                57107.3295670365, 68610.7672078486, 68974.0419745275, 63599.9002699614, 
                                47370.0886728576, 40298.4023452974, 48089.0718267054, 74934.8997999821, 
                                81332.8498247429, 34715.6143235733, 38149.8130708784, 50016.5254783694, 
                                15510.828443256, 11677.4399553228, 39174.1270562218, 26845.8279732768, 
                                33243.7779980375), code1 = c(253L, 253L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 
                                                             261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 
                                                             259L, 259L, 259L), code2 = c(252L, 251L, 253L, 252L, 260L, 258L, 
                                                                                          251L, 256L, 257L, 259L, 254L, 255L, 253L, 252L, 258L, 251L, 256L, 
                                                                                          257L, 254L, 255L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  mutate(codes2 = lag(codes)) %>%
  mutate_all(list(as.integer)) %>%
  left_join(., table2, by=c("codes"="code1", "codes2"="code2")) %>% 
  select(-codes2)

#>   codes     dist
#> 1   251       NA
#> 2   253 50226.44
#> 3   259 34715.61
#> 4   261 48089.07
```